# Android statusbar color in Embarcadero RAD Studio, C++

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, c++builder, firemonkey

EDIT:

I managed to remove current background of status bar (and also accidently background of navigation bar) using this code

```
ANativeActivity_setWindowFlags(PANativeActivity(System::DelphiActivity),
TJWindowManager_LayoutParams::JavaClass->FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS,
TJWindowManager_LayoutParams::JavaClass->FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

Still don't know how to add new background color

This will not work:

```
_di_JWindow androidWindow =  SharedActivity()->getWindow();
androidWindow->setStatusBarColor(17170432);
```

=====================================================================

Original post:

I'm trying to colorize the status bar of an android app made with FireMonkey/RAD Studio.

To achieve it in Java I usually use this code:

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

In RAD Studio I'm trying to do it like this

First I  include Android libs in header:

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
#include <FMX.Helpers.Android.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNIBridge.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.Os.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.Util.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.App.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.Jni.hpp>
#endif
```

Then when I'm trying to call:

```
JWindow androidWindow =  JNativeActivity::getWindow();
```

I get over 100 errors like the following:

```
[bccaarm Error] HeaderFooterTemplate.cpp(67): call to non-static member function without an object argument
[bccaarm Error] HeaderFooterTemplate.cpp(67): variable type 'Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::JWindow' is an abstract class
  sysmac.h(327): unimplemented pure virtual method 'QueryInterface' in 'JWindow'
  sysmac.h(328): unimplemented pure virtual method 'AddRef' in 'JWindow'
  sysmac.h(329): unimplemented pure virtual method 'Release' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp(763): unimplemented pure virtual method 'equals' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp(764): unimplemented pure virtual method 'getClass' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp(765): unimplemented pure virtual method 'hashCode' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp(766): unimplemented pure virtual method 'notify' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp(767): unimplemented pure virtual method 'notifyAll' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp(768): unimplemented pure virtual method 'toString' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp(769): unimplemented pure virtual method 'wait' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp(770): unimplemented pure virtual method 'wait' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp(771): unimplemented pure virtual method 'wait' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp(18831): unimplemented pure virtual method 'addContentView' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp(18832): unimplemented pure virtual method 'addFlags' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp(18833): unimplemented pure virtual method 'clearFlags' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp(18834): unimplemented pure virtual method 'closeAllPanels' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp(18835): unimplemented pure virtual method 'closePanel' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp(18836): unimplemented pure virtual method 'findViewById' in 'JWindow'
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp(18837): unimplemented pure virtual method 'getAllowEnterTransitionOverlap' in 'JWindow'
```

This are my first steps with C++, so I'm not sure I am doing it right.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using Embarcadero's JNI wrapper classes correctly.  The translation would look more like this instead:

```
_di_JActivity activity = SharedActivity();
// or: _di_JActivity activity = TAndroidHelper::Activity;

_di_JWindow window = activity->getWindow();
window->clearFlags(TJWindowManager_LayoutParams::JavaClass->FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window->addFlags(TJWindowManager_LayoutParams::JavaClass->FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window->setStatusBarColor(activity->getResources()->getColor(...));
// I don't know how to translate R.color.my_statusbar_color
```

However, with that said, Embarcadero's definition of the `JWindow` interface *does not* include the [`Window.setStatusBarColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)) method <sup>1</sup>  that was added in API Level 21 (Android 5, Lollipop).  So, unless you manually define your own JNI interface for the `Window` class in your own code, you won't be able to call `setStatusBarColor()` in C++Builder unless you resort to either making the call in Java code is that called by your C++ code, or use Reflection.

<sup>1</sup>: unless it was added in 10.1 Berlin, which I don't have installed. It is not present in 10.0 Seattle.

Comment: setStatusBarColor() is now available in 10.1 which I use.

The following code won't work
`window->clearFlags(TJWindowManager_LayoutParams::JavaClass->FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);`

It causes exception `Only the original thread 
that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Instead I have tried:
`ANativeActivity_setWindowFlags(PANativeActivity(System::DelphiActivity),TJWindowManager_LayoutParams::JavaClass->FLAG ... `

At this step I got background color of the statusbar removed - it is transparent, as so the navigation bar (unfortunately), and probably adds blank ActionBar.

Comment: The "only the original thread" error is pretty self-explanatory. Android UIs are tied to the thread context that creates them.  You can't access UI objects across thread boundaries. If you have a worker thread that is trying to manipulate a UI created by the main thread, you must delegate to the main thread for that manipulation.